# Javascript function in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm developing an app with django. I'm trying to implement a score counter, based on how many people is watching you, through your webcam.

I implemented a function to get the number of people that are watching you in live. Now I would like to have an other count that takes the existing Score of the user and add, every minute, one point for every people that are watching.

Here is the function to get the number of people watching:

```
  var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
  var id = url[3];

setInterval(function() {
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://myxml",
       success: parseXml
   });
}, 2000);

function parseXml(xml){
   $(xml).find("user").each(function() {

           if($(this).attr("id") === id ) {
               $(".Score").html($(this).attr("count"))
           }
       });
}
```

It works perfectly.

Now, here is the function I try to implement to get the existing score and add points to it:

```
   setInterval(function UserScore(){
      var self = $(this),
      score=self.attr('existing-score'),
      $(".PlayerScore").html($(this).attr("Score"+"existing-score"))
   }, 60000);
```

and the html to render it:

```
 <div class="PlayerScore" existing-score="{{ dub.user.userprofile.score }}"></div>
```

This function doesn't work. Nothing appears.

I'm really new in both Django and Javascript, so I guess there must be a lot of mistakes in this function. So any help would be very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You're mistaking `;` and `,` . In the UserScore() function, you have put `,` at the end of the lines, where `;` were required. Also, try to use a Javascript debugger (like Chrome developers tools, or Firebug), you'll know where your code fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  var score = $(".PlayerScore").attr('existing-score');
  var watchers = $(".Score").attr("count");
  $(".PlayerScore").html($(this).attr(score+watchers))
}, 60000);
```

There are a few changes here.

- User the `var` keyword to keep your variable declarations local to the current scope. Otherwise you're declaring global variables, and you will eventually stomp over some other variable with the same name. Very hard to debug.
- There is no need to name the function `UserScore`, just make it anonymous.
- Get the existing `score` as a value, and get the number of `watchers` as a value.
- Set the new `PlayerScore` to these values combine. `PlayerScore` is a class, I don't know if this is intentional, but it makes more sense if it was an `id`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to apply your solution, but it does not look to work. About PlayerScore, it was not intentional, and it does not correspond to any of my classes. May be the problem comes from that?